# Parse JObject into a mixed object (static + dynamic fields)

Tags: json.net

given the following json

```
{
    "$$href": "http://localhost:8080/url1",
    "name": "Sebastian Slutzky"
}
```

I'd like to deserialize it into an object like this one

```
public class DomainObject
{
    [JsonProperty("$$href")]
    public string href { get; set; }
    public JObject this[string key] => throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

so that arbitrary properties (like `name` can be accessed dynamically)

```
 var href = domainObject.href;
 var name = domainObject["name"] as string;
```

My current implementation is by passing the JObject to the constructor of my object, and decorate it (i.e. composition). Is there a way of solving this by inheritance instead (i.e. by extending JObject? 
Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`JsonExtensionData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm). For example

```
public class DomainObject
{
    [JsonProperty("$$href")]
    public string href { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> UnknownTypes;

    public JToken this[string key] => UnknownTypes[key];
}
```

The Indexer now allows you to retrieve the values of dynamic properties with key as the following.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DomainObject>(json);
var name = result["name"].Value<string>();
```